# Late/early for numbers other than age/year

Tags: numbers

When referring to age or to periods in time, it is quite common to use expressions such as

> He is in his *late twenties*

or

> The best music was produced in the *early eighties*

I have recently heard somebody use it in the sense of

> The number of shoes I own is in the *late thirties/early forties*.

Is that an acceptable use of late/early?

Comment: High and low, generally.

Comment: *Number of shoes* is not about time, so naturally **late** has no business to be in the sentence.

Comment: For numbers, it's *high and low* generally, instead of *early and late*.

Comment: There's no problem with it, early can be used to show a position in a series of numbers (not necessarily time periods) so _early forties_ is anything in the sequence 40-44, _late thirties_ is anything in the sequence 35-39, but most people would be more comfortable with high/low as has been mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously a subjective issue. The two existing answers both endorse OP's usage, but I don't.

There are various contexts where you can reasonably use a figurative temporal reference in a superficially "scalar" sense - for example, *the **early** pages of a book* (though for reasons I can't pin down, *the **late** pages* doesn't work for me, only ***later***). But that's because we normally start reading a book at the beginning; page numbers increase as time passes.

For contexts like OP's "number of shoes" I can only envisage using a temporal reference if there's a similarly obvious link between the passage of time and an increasing scalar value. For example,...

> *"How many blu-ray movies do I have? Let's see - I got my blu-ray player about three years ago, and I add another disc to my movie collection every month or so. It must be up to the late thirties by now."*

Comment: `the passage of time and an increasing scalar value` I think most married men know that it is a fact that _as time passes the number of shoes [owned by one's wife] increases_. :)

Comment: @Frank: Very true. But I still think to "justify" a time-based quantifier you'd normally probably want/need to explicitly reference something calling attention to the connection between *passing time* and *increasing number* in the specific context.

Answer (score 1):

Quite acceptable. Though an unusual expression, it is something I would ascribe to someone who tries to infuse their speech with wider-than-average vocabulary and idiom, even a hint of elegance. Be careful not to overdo it though.

Comment: Ho hum. I must get on your nerves sometimes, but I feel I have to downvote this. To me, usages such as *"The number of shoes I own is in the late thirties"*, or *"The temperature was in the early nineties"* are totally unacceptable, so -1

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why? You exhibit the most hideous proscriptivism!

Comment: I know, and it does make me feel slightly uncomfortable. Usually on ELU ***I'm*** the one who sees nothing wrong with creatively ignoring "the rules". In this case, I think it's a bending of the rules too far to apply figurative "temporal" usages to simple scalar values. You presumably wouldn't accept *"I own **after/before** 30 pairs of shoes"*, so obviously we agree at the margins. But you're more tolerant than me of usages that get *near* to that "unacceptable" limit.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You mean "*You're more tolerant than **I***" ;)

Comment: +1 It's not common but it's not wrong. Early can be used in series and from that late probably can too. "Near the limit" is still not "over the limit".

Comment: @Frank: In contexts like this, you must accept that "It's not wrong" sounds like a claim to have the backing of some higher "grammar authority", which is misleading. In reality, *any* judgement on this usage is subjective, and anything anyone says should be understood as being prefaced by **IMHO** (i.e. - it's not fair to imply you have some "specialist knowledge" about "the rules").

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand 'early pages of a book' to mean the pages at the beginning of the series of pages starting at or around #1. A lot of factual books don't require you to read from start to end so it's not 'time based' at all. I don't think that is specialist knowledge.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Are there any 'rules'?

Comment: @Frank: The fact that *some* people read *some* books "non-sequentially" is irrelevant. Because most people read from start to end, and this inevitably takes *time*, it's reasonable to speak of *earlier/later **pages***. But I don't see how that allows you to speak of a specific page as being *in the late thirties*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The books are non-sequential, like a dictionary or something like Haynes manuals. Haynes always had brake calipers in the the early sections and gearboxes in the later sections and you didn't need to read about brakes if you wanted to overhaul a gearbox. The question is about the use of _early_ without reference to time; 'early section' clearly is - it just means nearer the front cover of the book. I'm not saying that it's commonplace to use _early_ without reference to time, I'm just saying there are uses for it so it can't be 'wrong'.

Comment: @Frank: I know what you're saying. But just because you can refer to the early pages of a book does *not* mean OP's "number of shoes in the early thirties" is valid. If you don't have a problem with it that's just your position. It's an unacceptable usage to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It would be a very odd usage to me as well (shoes), I was just trying to point out that Kris' comment which denounced the usage specifically because it wasn't related to time was incorrect. I'll be surprised if I ever hear someone say 'My shoes number in the late thirties' but I would immediately understand what they meant and I'd assume they also meant pairs, so somewhere in the early seventies individually. ;)

Answer (score -1):

I'm voting it up one for creative SPEECH. If it were written, I might downvote, but since P SAID that about shoes, I approve. I myself might say, "Oh, 30 and change," borrowing from monetary transactions to say I'm sure I have 30 but not yet 40.